# Why is $2(3\times 2-5) = 2(1)= 2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My first post here :)

So anyways this question might be stupid, but why is $2(3\times2-5) =2\times1$?

I've verified this in CAS and in the textbooks's soulution

The whole equation is:

$x-2(3x-5)=0$

$x = 2$ (this is verified)
then,

according to the answer sheet:
$ 2-(3\times2-5)=2-2(1)=0$

Thanks for any answers :D

Sincerely

Oskar,
Upper secondary school

Comment: Your title and your body ask different questions.

Comment: Also your equation is not an ODE. The equation is $(x-2)(3x-5)=0$ right?

Comment: Whoops. But the whole question is why 2(2*3-5)=2(1)

Comment: Because $2\times3-5=6-5=1$

Comment: well 6-5 is 1 yes. Im stupid and tired. Sorry to bother you *facepalm*

Comment: @Dadahu that's just a simple calculation. But I'm not sure why are you stuck? State the problem exactly. Do you have problem with solving the equation or not?